# Prove that $E$ is measurable if and only if $E\cap K$ is measurable for every compact set $K$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The forward implication is straightforward. However, I have a little bit trouble proving the other direction. First of all, someone suggests that I could choose a favorable compact set $K$ and show $E$ is measurable. I don't understand this logic. If this is true, then we only proved that if the intersection of $E$ and the compact set $K$ we choose is measurable, then $E$ is measurable. If $K$ is something else, this might not hold. Can someone tell me why this is a legitimate proof? Or maybe it is not.

My idea was to choose a open set $G\supset K$. If we can somehow prove that $E\cap G$ is measurable for all $G$, then we can say that $E$ is measurable by referring to the theorem that $E$ is measurable if and only if $E\cap (a,b)$ is measurable for every bounded open interval $(a,b)$. But I have problem showing $E\cap G$ is measurable.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $A_n := E \cap [-n,n]$ is measurable for all $n \in \Bbb N$. But:

$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = E \cap \Bbb R = E$$

Hence $E$ is measurable.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm assuming below that the definition of "measurable" you are using is "differs from a Borel set by a null set," or that you at least know this characterization.*

Suppose $E\cap K$ is measurable for all compact $K$. Let $K_i=[-i, i]$, $E_i=E\cap K_i$ - so $E_i$ is measurable and $E=\bigcup E_i$.

Since each $E_i$ is measurable, there are Borel sets $B_i$ and null sets $N_i$ such that $E_i=B_i\Delta N_i$. What can you say about $\bigcup B_i$ compared to $E$?